# Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter for Listview

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I try to display the variable "response" inside a listview, but I failed to make the adapter. It has an error, "cannot resolve constructor arrayadapter, how can I resolve it?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements Callback {

    ListView mListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BDDRequest.GetRequest(this, new UserEmployeeInfo(), this);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listrequest);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, response);

        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onError() {
        //Show fallback message here
    }
}
```

Comment: the third param of the `ArrayAdapter` should be an `array` or any list which implements the `List` interface. [ArrayAdapter Constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Comment: Hummm.. ok but, i just wanna display my String "response"...  i'm suppose to change something in my adapter no ?

Comment: Ah, the amazing power of "Read the Fine Manual" (RTFM)!

Comment: there is no `ArrayAdapter` constructor which takes a third param as a `String`, you'll need to convert it to an `array` or `list`.

Comment: So, maybe i can use another method than ArrayAdapter ?

Comment: `ArrayAdapter` isn't a method. Have you read through its Javadocs, to one version of which @Ousmane Mahy Diaw linked you? It might have, say, a setter (mutator) method that could help you. Read the Fine Manual.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) you need to use as the last paramater in your constructor an `array` and not a simple `String`.

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But i want display a simple string, so, maybe there are another method than ArrayAdapter ?

Comment: `ArrayAdapter` isn't a method.

Comment: You need to display the `response` String in each item from the `ListView`?